# SOAP error. Not getting correct structure returned

Tags: php, soap

I have a website that contains a form that makes various SOAP requests at certain points. One of these requests gets a list of induction times returned and displays them to the user in order for them to pick one.
I am getting results returned fine from the SOAP service but unfortunately it seems to be not showing information correctly and even not displaying returned object keys at all. 
I have liased with one of the devs at the SOAP end and he says the service is fine and spitting out the cirrect information. He has provided a screentshot:

[image]

Here is my code to pull call the method I need for this information:

```
public function getInductionTimes($options) {
        $client = $this->createSoapRequest();
        $inductionTimes = $client->FITinductionlist($options);
        //die(print_r($inductionTimes));
        return $inductionTimes;
    }

    private function createSoapRequest() {
        $url = 'https://fitspace.m-cloudapps.com:444/FITSPACE/MHservice.asmx?WSDL';
        $options["connection_timeout"] = 25;
        $options["location"] = $url;
        $options['trace'] = 1;
        $options['style'] = SOAP_RPC;
        $options['use'] = SOAP_ENCODED;

        $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
        //die(print_R($client->__getFunctions()));
        return $client;
    }
```

As you can see I print_r the code right after I have received it to check what I am getting returned and it is this:

[image]

As you can see this IDdtstring field is getting completely ignored. 
Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening? Is it something to do with encoding? I can't seem to get anywhere on this issue!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the fields correctly, including IDdtstring, using your basic code.  Perhaps you are not sending the parameters correctly?

```
function getInductionTimes($options) {
    $client = createSoapRequest();
    $inductionTimes = $client->FITinductionlist($options);
    die(print_r($inductionTimes));
    return $inductionTimes;
}

function createSoapRequest() {
    $url = 'https://fitspace.m-cloudapps.com:444/FITSPACE/MHservice.asmx?WSDL';
    $options["connection_timeout"] = 25;
    $options["location"] = $url;
    $options['trace'] = 1;
    $options['style'] = SOAP_RPC;
    $options['use'] = SOAP_ENCODED;

    $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
    //die(print_R($client->__getFunctions()));
    return $client;
}

getInductionTimes(array("IDDate" => "2013-06-28T13:00:00+01:00", "GYMNAME" => "Bournemouth"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by adding the line of code into my SOAP options array which I then presume was an issue with my WSDL being cached in PHP:

$options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;